# My PHP page refer to Error:Missing controller

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, xdebug

I´m new in PHP and creating dynamic webpages and after I installed Apache and my PHP IDE(codelobster) I face a serious problem.I really don´t know what I´m doing wrong but when I create new PHP project and I try to open it via my browser through localhost/...it always return me back a error page with this description:

> Error:Missing controller
>   Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException

My php file is called oneironaut.php so it gives me also:
Oneironaut.phpController could not be found.

In the case you tried to access a plugin controller make sure you added it to your composer file or you use the autoload option for the plugin.

> Error: Create the class Oneironaut.phpController below in file:
>   src\Controller\Oneironaut.phpController.php

I tried to create different projects like with different names and there was always this bug diference only with name of my .php webpage.So I think this must be some system error and something in my xampp/php or Apache settings must change.Maybe there could be some connection with my unfunctional debugger , I tried to download Xdebug from https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and even though I follow instructions on this website and another websites too I can´t successfully get xdebug extensions into my computer.So in this some help will be highly appreciated too.

So give me someone please help what to do with these problems? Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be happening because the server is loading files in "case-sensitive" mode.

You call your PHP file "oneironaut.php", however, the page is looking for "Oneironaut.php"

A similar question has been answered here, please try:
[Missing Controller Error on remote server using Beta 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583487/missing-controller-error-on-remote-server-using-beta-3)